# WordPress -- Plug-In To Assign Images To Users/Clients?

Tags: image, wordpress, plugins, gallery

As a graphic designer, I am wondering if either:

1. there is a WordPress plugin that will allow me, as an administrator, to upload a client image and assign it to a user profile; or
2. there is a simple way to hack WP into doing what I stated in #1?

I want clients to have the ability to log-in once to my WordPress site, and to click on a "user gallery" page which will only show the images/graphics assigned/completed for them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this plugin should work...

[**User Specific Content**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-specific-content/)

This Plugin allows you to select specific users by user name, or by role name who can view a specific post content or page content.